# How to delete a thread in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, garbage-collection

Here is the important part of my Server class:

```
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8000);

        while (true)
        {                                               
            Socket s = server.accept();             
            System.out.println("Client connected from " + s.getLocalAddress().getHostName());   

            Client chat = new Client(s);
            Thread t = new Thread(chat);
            t.start();
        }
```

As you can see, it creates a new Instance of my Client-Class, which is a thread, everytime a new connection is being established. Here is the important part of my client-class:

```
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner in = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        String newLine = null;

        while (true)
        {
            try{
                newLine = in.nextLine();
            }
            catch(NoSuchElementException io){
                //Delete this instance
            }
            if(clientName==null){
                clientName = newLine;
            }
            else{
                out.println(clientName+":  "+newLine);
                out.flush();
            }
        }
```

Right now, I am catching a disconnect of a client with a try/catch, which reacts to missing nextLine of my socket inputstream. As soon as the client closes his chat client, it will jump into the catch clause everytime, considering that there is no inputstream anymore.

However, due to performance issues, I would now like to remove this Client-Instance, considering that it isn't being used anymore. However, I don't really have any idea how to do this.

I had one idea so far:
 Make my client-class observable, and listen to it in my Server class. As soon as I enter the catch clause, I will notify my observer, which is my Server-class in this case, and tell it to set the reference on this Client-Instance to null, effectively removing any references and leaving it to be dealt with by the Garbage collector.

However, I feel that this is not the way to go here, but honestly, I can't think of any other option right now.

Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your `Client` class is either extending from `Thread` or implementing `Runnable`. Either ways, your `Client` class is running an infinite `while(true)` loop. Unless this loop exits, the `Client` class won't be garbage collected. Therefore, you need to break out of the `while(true)` loop.

```
while (true) {
    try{
       newLine = in.nextLine();
    }
    catch(NoSuchElementException io){
        break;// exit the infinite loop
    }
    if(clientName==null) {
       clientName = newLine;
    }
    else {
       out.println(clientName+":  "+newLine);
       out.flush();
    }
}
```

Once you break out of the `while(true)` loop, the run method of the `Client` thread will complete and the `Client` object will be eligible for garbage collection. You don't have to explicitly delete the `Client` object as this is done by the garbage collector when an object is found to be eligible for garbage collection. (Assuming that the `while(true)` loop is inside your `run` method or inside a method that calls `run`)

Answer (score 3):

If you aren't keeping a reference to `Client` anywhere (as it seems in your code), you don't need to do anything (except close resources).

When your thread will exit (for example by return/breaking from your catch block) your `Chat` object will be eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: `The thread will exit and your Chat object will be eligible for garbage collection`. Not sure if this statement is correct. Notice the `while(true)` loop that won't let the `Client` Runnable get garbage collected. The OP will need to break out of the loop for the thread to exit.

Comment: @ChetanKinger not until another client connects, then the reference to the previous one will be lost, thus making previous chat for GC. Or isn't it? Oh nvm, I just saw the "thread loop" part" :)

Comment: @zubergu No. The `chat` reference will disappear once the while loop rolls over to block at `accept()`, so as soon as the thread dies, the client's data is gone.

Comment: @Kayaman Agreed. Although, the thread won't die until the `while(true)` loop exits. What you said `you don't need to do anything (except close resources).` is not really true. The OP will need to break out of the while loop. See my answer.

Comment: @Kayaman now you got me confused with your last comment, why blocking on accept() frees up chat for GC?

Comment: Well it is implied that the thread must exit, but there's no manual clean-up required afterwards.

Comment: @Kayaman It's not implied because you say this `you don't need to do anything (except close resources)`. This answer is incorrect without correcting this statement.

Comment: @zubergu Well the main thread will block on `accept()`, to wait for another client. The `client` variable will fall out of scope when the `while` loop goes round.

Comment: @Kayaman It's implied for someone who knows anything about threads. The OP clearly doesn't know this as evident from the question. . The statement `The thread will exit` is incorrect because from the code that the OP posted, the thread will never exit. The statement `you don't need to do anything (except close resources)` makes it even more evident that you believe that the `Thread will exit` on its own.

Comment: @ChetanKinger The answer might have been lacking, but it was in no way incorrect.

Comment: @Kayaman So the reference falls out of scope on the end of every iteration, or , as I thought previously, when it gets reassigned in next iteration?

Comment: @zubergu Scope is limited by `{ }`. It can't hold a value over multiple iterations of the loop unless you declare it before your `while` loop.

Comment: @Kayaman Breaking out of the loop is an absolute necessity for the `Client` thread to be garbage collected. Without this information, the answer was incorrect.

Comment: @ChetanKinger Not incorrect. I was answering different aspects of the question, and since you're not the asker of the question your opinion of "incorrect" is irrelevant.

Comment: @Kayaman I don't believe there was any other aspect of the question to be answered other than how to have the `Client` class deleted. Exiting the while loop is an absolute necessity to answer this aspect. Don't get me wrong. My intention is not to argue with you but to point out that without exiting the while loop, any answer to this question can never be correct. I am not sure why you feel otherwise.